# How to interpret the address converted from inet_pton?

Tags: c, ip, ip-address

I am confused with the value I get from specified address, when the address was converted by the `inet_pton` function to `struct in_addr`. Having this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(){
    char str[4];
    inet_pton(AF_INET, "1.2.3.4", (int*)str);
    printf("%i\n", *((int*)str));
}
```

I get

```
67305985
```

so address `1.2.3.4` was converted to "network address" (man page of inet_pton) of value `67305985`, which I do not understand. I know the function saves the converted value to type of `struct in_addr`, but this is basically a int, so I can cast it to an `int` (which I did) and get this nonsense. So How should I interpret the value `67305985` from address `1.2.3.4`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value you're getting is the decimal representation of the byte values 1, 2, 3, and 4 interpreted in little endian byte order.

If you print each byte individually, you'll see they contain the values 1, 2, 3, and 4.

```
char str[4];
int i;
inet_pton(AF_INET, "1.2.3.4", (int*)str);
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", str[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Comment: I do not get it. In what encoding is `67305985` is sequential numbers mapped to sequential 1,2,3,4? Neither hexa nor ascii, what is it?

Comment: In hex, 67305985 is 04030201.  The `inet_pton` function puts the bytes in network byte order, i.e. most-significant-byte first.  The bytes are reversed when interpreting them as an `int` because your machine is little-endian.

Comment: I know little endian , but why `85==04`, `59==03`, `30=02`, `67==01`? What encoding is that?

Comment: @milanHrabos it's not 85==04, 59==03, 30=02, 67==01.  It's 67305985  == 04030201.  You can't match up digits in two different bases like that.

Comment: still do not get it. I am not messing with bases, but 85 != 0x04.  The `67305985 == 04030201` just does not make sense, neither in x16, nor in x10. I just does not know how to interpret or derived the number `67305985 `

Comment: @milanHrabos You're trying to match a decimal number and a hex number digit by digit.  You can't do that. If you had 100 decimal / 064 hex, you wouldn't compare 1 == 0 and 00 == 64.  67305985 decimal is 04030201 hex.  The bytes of that number are stored in order as 01 02 03 04.  When you read those bytes as a `int` it takes the first byte as the lowest and the last byte at the highest.